# OpenSuse - have to be logged in to see on network

Tags: networking, opensuse

I have 2 machines - a windows 7 and an opensuse server.  they both use the same router.

I noticed when setting up xrdp (remote desktop), I could only remote desktop into my opensuse 11.3 machine from my windows 7 machine when I was logged into the opensuse machine locally (tried as both my user account and root).

I remoted in, and was logged in locally already, so I logged out locally, and it killed my remote connection.

Also, when I ping the openususe IP from windows machine, I only get a response back when I am logged in locally to the opensuse machine.  How do I fix this? I have not setup up an networking with samba or anything

Answer (score 1):

Chances are very high your OpenSUSE install is set up to use NetworkManager to manage networking connections, which is a userspace tool. If you want OpenSUSE to be on the network without a logged in user, you need to:

1. Go into YaST
2. Go to Network Settings
3. Go to the "Global Options" tab
4. Check "Traditional Method with ifup"

That will set it up to get a connection on boot, instead of on-login.